# What's the difference between /media and media/ in a .gitignore file?

Tags: git, gitignore

I've tried both and I'm getting similar results. Haven't been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The leading and trailing slashes each add a restriction to what is matched.

- **`media`**: Without either slash, it will match both files and directories in the current directory and all sub-directories.
- **`media/`**: Adding a trailing slash means that it will only match directories in the current directory and all sub-directories. (**not files**)
- **`/media`**: With a leading slash, it will match both files and directories, but only in the current directory. (**not sub-directories**)
- **`/media/`**: With both a leading and trailing slash, it will match only the directory "media" in the current directory. (**not files and not sub-directories**)

The [.gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) is reasonably clear on these:

### Use a trailing `/` to specify a directory or folder

> If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, `foo/` will match a directory `foo` and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link `foo` (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in Git).

For `media/`: This will match any directory/folders named "media" in the directory in which the *.gitignore* file exists, or any subdirectories. It will not match files named "media". For instance, "media/foo.c", and "bar/media/foo.c" will match, but the file "foobar/media" will not.

### Use a leading `/` to specify the match must begin in the current directory

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, "/*.c" matches "cat-file.c" but not "mozilla-sha1/sha1.c".

For `/media`:

`/media` will match all filepaths from the directory in which the *.gitignore* file exists which *begin* with `media`. It won't match paths in sub-directories which just happen to contain "media", but which did not start with "media" in the current directory. For instance, "media/foo.c" will match, but "foo/media/bar.c" will not.

Comment: Could you explain the difference between `media/` and `media`?

Comment: @Zorgan I've added a bit more explanation about all four combinations to the beginning of this answer. Does this cover what you were wondering about?

Comment: I've got `media` in my `.gitignore` - but it's only ignoring directories, not files. I've got a `media.html` in root dir (where `.gitignore` exists), as well as another `media.html` in a subdirectory and neither of them are being ignored. Any idea why? FYI I'm seeing all my ignored files via `git status --ignored`.

Comment: @Zorgan `media` doesn't match `media.html`. `media.html` is a different name. If you want it to match a different file name that *contains* "media", then you need to use a wildcard `*`. For example: `media.*`.

Answer (score 3):

By default, a gitignore pattern is recursive, i.e. it will ignore files or folders matching the pattern in any subfolder of the one containing the `.gitignore` file.

By prefixing the pattern with `/`, you disable the recursivity and the pattern only applies to to files or folders directly inside the folder containing the `.gitignore` file.

By suffixing the pattern with `/`, you make only match folders (and not files).

If you combine both, you match only folders in the current folder and no subfolders.

[.gitignore doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format).

So if you only have one `media` folder in the current directory, both patterns will match it and the result will be the same.